# Unsure which azure queue should I use

Tags: azure, queue, azureservicebus

Currently, I have a problem handling data which I have sent from application to azure queue. The data I sent required to be sent FIFO but the Azure Queue cannot guarantee to be in order. Whereas Azure Service Bus Queue was guaranteed to be FIFO.

I am not sure is Azure Service Bus Queue has any differences with the Azure Queue.

Comment: FIFO is only supported with Azure Service Bus when Sessions are used. Storage queues do not support ordering.

Answer (score 1):

As a solution architect/developer, **you should consider using Storage queues** when:

- Your application must store over 80 GB of messages in a queue, where the messages have a lifetime shorter than 7 days.
- Your application wants to track progress for processing a message inside of the queue. This is useful if the worker processing a message crashes. A subsequent worker can then use that information to continue from where the prior worker left off.
- You require server side logs of all of the transactions executed against your queues.

As a solution architect/developer, **you should consider using Service Bus queues** when:

- Your solution must be able to receive messages without having to poll the queue. With Service Bus, this can be achieved through the use of the long-polling receive operation using the TCP-based protocols that Service Bus supports.
- Your solution requires the queue to provide a guaranteed first-in-first-out (FIFO) ordered delivery.
- You want a symmetric experience in Azure and on Windows Server (private cloud). For more information, see [Service Bus for Windows Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn282144.aspx).
- Your solution must be able to support automatic duplicate detection.
- You want your application to process messages as parallel long-running streams (messages are associated with a stream using the [SessionId](/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.sessionid) property on the message). In this model, each node in the consuming application competes for streams, as opposed to messages. When a stream is given to a consuming node, the node can examine the state of the application stream state using transactions.
- Your solution requires transactional behavior and atomicity when sending or receiving multiple messages from a queue.
- The time-to-live (TTL) characteristic of the application-specific workload can exceed the 7-day period.
- Your application handles messages that can exceed 64 KB but will not likely approach the 256 KB limit.
- You deal with a requirement to provide a role-based access model to the queues, and different rights/permissions for senders and receivers.
- Your queue size will not grow larger than 80 GB.
- You want to use the AMQP 1.0 standards-based messaging protocol. For more information about AMQP, see Service Bus AMQP Overview.
- You can envision an eventual migration from queue-based point-to-point communication to a message exchange pattern that enables seamless integration of additional receivers (subscribers), each of which receives independent copies of either some or all messages sent to the queue. The latter refers to the publish/subscribe capability natively provided by Service Bus.
- Your messaging solution must be able to support the "At-Most-Once" delivery guarantee without the need for you to build the additional infrastructure components.
- You would like to be able to publish and consume batches of messages.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted

Comment: Since this is pretty much the exact text from the web page you linked to, it's best just to provide this link, as a comment to the question.

Comment: well, i dont think it really matters, tbh I've provided both

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through this link before. I not good at decision making. So come here to give me some confidence to which I should be using.. I am thinking Service Bus Queue is more appropriate for my scenario

Comment: well, this clearly says you NEED to use Service Bus if you require FIFO.

Answer (score 0):

Messages in Storage queues are typically first-in-first-out, but sometimes they can be out of order; for example, when a message's visibility timeout duration expires (for example, as a result of a client application crashing during processing). When the visibility timeout expires, the message becomes visible again on the queue for another worker to dequeue it. At that point, the newly visible message might be placed in the queue (to be dequeued again) after a message that was originally enqueued after it.

You will find this article helpful in making the decision for your case: [Storage Queues and Service Bus Queue comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted). **It compares some of the fundamental queuing capabilities provided by Storage queues and Service Bus queues**.

Also read [Get started with Service Bus Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues).